# adding ressources and services code to a Jlink image

Tags: java, resources, java-9, jlink

now suppose you have an application that let (advanced) users write ressource files and compile service code (from templates)

before Java 9 I did that with two different jars: one was theApp.jar and the other theAdppDeploy.jar the later being generated on site from templates.

with the modular system it still could be done (though we will have cross-dependencies across modules)

but is it possible to think about a JImage generated by Jlink and having the (advanced) user toy with this image by adding ressource files and service code?
How to do that (if possible)?

thanks

Comment: The question needs a bit more detail. When you say "resources", do you mean resources that are located with Class or ClassLoader.getResourceXXXX? Maybe you mean ResourceBundle? You mention services, do you mean ServiceLoader? In any case, both ServiceLoader and ResourceBundle have been updated to work with modules. All the details are in the javadoc. On run-time images, the conf directory is the only supported located where to add or edit files.

Comment: yes I mean resources located by getResource (for instance to populate a Properties object) for service I mean ServiceLoader ... I know how to work with those in modules and jars  (and even know about the jrt URLS). BUT the question is precisely how to add resources and services codes to an existing Jimage generated by Jlink.

Comment: There is no supported way to modify a module in a run-time image. You can you run with `--patch-module` to override or augment resources but that probably isn't what you want. For services then you can deploy addition service providers on the module path, you can't add additional service providers to the run-time image.

Comment: the idea is not to modify an existing module (note that while using jars there was a different jar -here named "theAppDeploy.jar"-) so no code is going to be modified in the Jimage... but I want to add an additional module  with service providers and ressource data. So to follow your comment the question is: where might the "module path" be when you run an app from a jlink generated Jimage?

Comment: When you say "Jimage" then I think you mean a run-time image (jimage is a JDK internal container format). If you have additional modules then deploy them on the module path (--module-path). If a module in the run-time image `uses` a service and you have a module on the module path that `provides` an implementation then it will be resolved.

Comment: Hmm. do you mean this?: the document generated by Jlink has a launcher the end-user can click on to start the app ... then instead create a script (.bat or .sh) that runs the app with "java --module-path theLauncher" ... possible. I am now wondering where is the best place to put the modular jars around the jlink-generated document ...

Comment: as a matter of fact I tried to modify the launcher script in "bin" to have a --module-path or an upgrade-module-path that points to additional module code (or jar)... but nothing actually worked ...the java executable in "bin" does not uses the corresponding options (apparently) ... so (?)

Answer (score 2):

it can be done:

put your deploy jar in the conf directory of your image then edit the launcher script with  `JLINK_VM_OPTIONS='--patch-module com.mycompany.mymodule=../conf/deploy.jar'`

that works (though there is some confusion about the name for the module ... but who cares?)... but there may be also some problems about the current running directory (I would rather have some kind of jrt URL to describe that)...

anybody with a better option?